# Can you use sequential #if blocks in an autoexp.dat preview?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, debugging

I have a quadratic equation struct, and I'd like to make it look nicer in the visual studio 2008 debugger. Here's the struct:

```
struct QuadraticEquation
{
    float squareCoefficent; float linearCoefficent; float yIntersection; 
}
```

I'd like it to appear as a properly formatted equation in the debugger:

```
3.0x^2 - 1.3x + 6.5
```

Here's the autoexp.dat preview script:

```
QuadraticEquation{
    preview
    (
        #if($c.squareCoefficent != 0.0f)
        (
            #($c.squareCoefficent, "x^2")
        )
        #if($c.linearCoefficent < 0.0f)
        (
            #(" - ", -$c.linearCoefficent, "x")            
        )
        #elif($c.linearCoefficent > 0.0f)
        (
            #(" + ", $c.linearCoefficent, "x")            
        )
        #if($c.yIntersection < 0.0f)
        (
            #(" - ", -$c.yIntersection)            
        )
        #elif($c.yIntersection > 0.0f)
        (
            #(" + ", $c.yIntersection)            
        )
    )
}
```

Pretty straight forward. But when I run the code, I get the following error message:

`ERROR! Autoexp.dat:line(286) for 'QuadraticEquation': Failed to match ')' for preview/children rule`

The line number corresponds to the second #if branch, that starts `#if($c.linearCoefficent < 0.0f)...`

If I remove everything except the square coefficent branch, it doesn't error. If this means that I can't have sequential #if blocks, how else could I do what I want here - without dropping into a dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use nested `#if`'s to achieve something like this.  Check how `std::complex<*>` is done in the default `autoexp.dat`.

This will take a lot of typing to cover all possible combinations.  Do you really need that?  Maybe displaying it simply as a struct is good enough for practical purposes.

Comment: Yeah I'm not doing all those +/- combinations by hand - they can go jump. Thanks for pointing out `std::complex<*>`.